# Shared preference value as input to the JSONArray in Android

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

How to pass the shared preference  values as input to the JSONArray, I'm using the following code in my program, Kindly Help me,Thanks in Advance.

*shared prefernce to  get email id*
**pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("set", 0);** 
                                                    editor = pref.edit();

*Put the Shared Preference Value in RegisterActivity*

**editor.putString("email", inc_email.getText().toString());**

*Get the value from Shared Preference in LoginActivity*

**pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("set", 0);
        final String em=pref.getString("email","");**

*Parsing Value to service URL*

**String API="http://groups.com/projects/nic/main.php?email="+em+"&state="+state;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you forgot to commit changes?

Try:

```
editor.putString("email", inc_email.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

If you need JSON parsing, you may use this useful library https://jsonp.java.net/